# Why is Canada's unemployment rate higher than that of the US, UK, Germany and the Netherlands?

Tags: unemployment, natural-rate-unemployment, canada

Current unemployment rate in Canada is about 5.8% while countries such as the US, UK, Germany and the Netherlands have unemployment rates well below 5%. In addition, the current unemployment rate in Canada is the lowest on record. Why has it remained so high historically?

Comment: It is not the lowest on record, but the [lowest since 1976](https://tradingeconomics.com/canada/unemployment-rate), which is still very surprising.